# C++ Casting a 1D dynamic array to a 2D array to use usual indices (like arr[i][j])

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

My teacher showed me this way of casting a 1D dynamic array to a 2D array
to use the fancy  arr[i][j] syntax.

```
using myarr = int(*)[mat_size][mat_size];
int * data = new int[mat_size * mat_size];
myarr arr = (myarr)data;
```

Now it is possible to access element at pos [i][j] with

```
(*arr)[i][j]
```

instead of

```
data[i * mat_size + j].
```

Unfortunately I don't understand what's happening in this solution. Can someone please explain?

P. S. 
The solution works, but I don't understand it.
I don't get why the `myarr arr` points at the `data` variable, not at the actual data in memory. Wouldn't it be so, if we did `myarr arr = (myarr)&data` ? Also I googled, and couldn't find any similar solution. Is it bad to do it this way? Why nobody does this?

Comment: Supplement your formal education with these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Your teacher should teach you how to do this properly with `std::vector`

Comment: What is the problem? Won't compile? Compiles with warning? Compiles, no warnings, but doesn't behave correctly?

Comment: Unrelated: When I encounter something like this, I stick with `data[i * mat_size + j]`, but wrap it all up in a helper class like this one: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first line,

```
using myarr = int(*)[mat_size][mat_size];
```

You're simply declaring a type: `myarr` is a custom type representing a pointer to a 2D array of `int` values. The `using` here is similar to `typedef` if you've worked with any older versions of C++.

Then,

```
int* data = new int[mat_size * mat_size];
```

declares a 1-dimensional pointer. In memory, this is a single series of values.

Next,

```
myarr arr = (myarr)data;
```

creates a new variable of type `myarr` - also a simple pointer - and points it to the address of the original array pointer. The difference with this pointer is that, when dereferenced the first time, it's an array type; thus its dereferencing syntax following the first dereference is different: as a 2-dimensional array, you use two pairs of brackets.

**Notice, then, that this second array variable, in essence, *still accesses a 1-dimensional array* in the memory.** In the first reference statement you have,

```
(*arr)[i][j]
```

To properly index into the array, C++ compiles the bracket syntax so that it'll automatically multiply the first index by the number of items in a single row. This was defined as part of your `myarr`, and was declared to be `mat_size`. Then, after this, it'll automatically add the second index.

(p.s. also don't get confused by the `*arr` part - the extra `*` is there because the `myarr arr` variable points to the `data` *variable*, not to the actual data array itself.)

Then, in your second statement,

```
data[i * mat_size + j]
```

you're using the original pointer, which has a nice bracket dereferencing syntax, but only dereferences as a 1-dimensional array. Because of this, you have to do the indexing yourself, manually multiplying the `mat_size` by the first index (`i`), and then manually adding the second (`j`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I don't understand why the `myarr arr` points at the `data` variable, not at the actual data. Wouldn't it be so, if we did `myarr arr = (myarr)&data` ?